# How to configure axios interceptor globally with express?

Tags: typescript, axios, interceptor

I want to set up axios interceptor globally for all the http call from axios.
Our http call is wrapped in a typescript class `Foo`:

```
import Axios, axios from 'axios';
import { configAxios } from 'config';
class Foo {
   Foo() {
      configureAxios();
  }
   public callAxios() {
      axios.request() // send the http request
   }
}
default export new Foo();
```

In `config.ts` it defines the interceptor config:

```
export default function configAxios() {
     Axios.interceptors.request.use(req => { // config request });
     Axios.interceptors.response.use(res => { // config response });
}
```

But no request or response is intercepted.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't configure interceptors in a class constructor. That will add duplicates every time you create an instance of that class.

I would recommend creating a specific [Axios instance](https://axios-http.com/docs/instance) to use that has the interceptors bound to it...

```ts
// client.ts
import axios from "axios";

const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://example.com" // just an example
});

// Some example interceptors that add properties to the standard request config
// and read it in the response.

interface MyCustomConfig extends AxiosRequestConfig {
  myMagicProperty?: number;
}

client.interceptors.request.use<MyCustomConfig>((config) => ({
  ...config,
  myMagicProperty: performance.now(),
}), null, { synchronous: true });

client.interceptors.response.use((res) => {
  console.log((res.config as MyCustomConfig).myMagicProperty);
  return res;
});

export default client;
```

This way, you can still access the default instance (or create entirely new ones) without interceptors which can be handy for making authentication or token refresh requests. It also ensures your instance is only created and configured once.

Now simply use this instance in your class

```ts
import client from "./client";

class Foo {
  public callAxios() {
    client.request() // send the http request
  }
}

default export new Foo();
```

Comment: Ok I think this is getting me somewhere. Is it common to add an extra request header in the request interceptor and retrieve this specific header value in the response interceptor?

Comment: @dragonfly02 I couldn't possibly answer that as I don't know what anyone other than myself does with their interceptors. Personally, I wouldn't send anything in the request (eg headers) that wasn't expected by the API. You can always add extra properties into the `config` object itself which won't be sent but will be available to interceptors

Comment: Saw someone else says about `config` object as well; but I have to ask where is the `config` object? Is it on the `request`?

Comment: @dragonfly02 I've updated my answer with a simple example

Comment: Somehow `interceptor.request.use` doesn't allow to take a generic parameter?

Comment: @dragonfly02 assuming you mean `response.use` unfortunately no, you can only supply the response data type, not the config type

Comment: I meant `request.use` as shown in your answer. I just tried and it's a compile error to pass in the type parameter. Says expect 0 but got 1.

Comment: This is the signature of `use` on `AxiosInterceptorManager<V>`: `use(onFulfilled?: (value: V) => V | Promise<V>, onRejected?: (error: any) => any): number;`

Comment: @dragonfly02 what version of Axios are you using?

Comment: I am using Axios `0.21.0`

Comment: Yikes, [that's old](https://github.com/axios/axios/releases/tag/v0.21.0). I'd recommend using `0.27.2`